# Doing datetime math in a function call in an Oracle query

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Ok, I got the first part of my question answered, so here's the second part. :-) In a PLSQL query, I have criteria that looks like this:

```
where Doc3.clinicalDate >= ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateBegin)
    and Doc3.clinicalDate < ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateEnd)
```

Now, I don't want to use :DateEnd itself -- I want to add 1 day so that when it compares the datetime to midnight, I get midnight of the *next* day. Unfortunately, when I do

```
where Doc3.clinicalDate >= ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateBegin)
    and Doc3.clinicalDate < ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateEnd + 1)
```

I get "ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CONVERT_DATE_TO_ID'". ":DateEnd + interval '1' day" gives me "ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic" (where :DateEnd is bound to 31-MAY-2012). If I do "convert_date_to_id(add_months(:DateEnd, 1))", it works fine. Any thoughts? Thanks.

ETA: I should clarify that this is an SSRS 2008 R2 project, and `DateBegin` and `DateEnd` are defined in the report parameters as DateTime parameters. My current workaround involves setting the `:DateEnd` query parameter equal to the `@DateEnd` report parameter + 1, but I'm worried that someday I'll forget to document this properly and confuse the heck out of whomever's trying to maintain the report (and it might be me). I *don't* want to pass string parameters, as suggested before.

Comment: What data type is `clinicalDate`, and what are the parameter and return types for `convert_date_to_id`?

Comment: FUNCTION Convert_Date_to_ID (thedate IN Date) RETURN NUMERIC AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (thedate-to_date('01/01/1960','mm/dd/yyyy'))*1000000*86400;
END;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking that the parameters being DateTime is root of the problem.  Microsoft DateTime datatypes are way more granular than Oracle's in that it supports fractional seconds and Oracle DATE format does not (Oracle TIMESTAMP does however).

Since ADD_MONTHS just spits back whatever it's passed in DATE datatype (i.e. passed TIMESTAMP becomes DATE).  So maybe you can convert the parameter and add the day that way:

```
where Doc3.clinicalDate >= ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateBegin) 
    and Doc3.clinicalDate < ml.convert_date_to_id(CAST(:DateEnd as DATE)+1)
```

Alternatively, forget about conversions and date arithmetic on the parameters and subtract a day from the second clinicalDate:

```
where Doc3.clinicalDate >= ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateBegin) 
    and Doc3.clinicalDate - 1 < ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateEnd)
```

Comment: That second one won't work -- clinicalDate is a weird-ass timestampish thing, including an id relating to the workstation that made the edit. I'll check on your first suggestion, though. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, that worked, and it put the conversion right where I wanted it -- the more places to check, the more chance I'll miss one. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `ml.convert_date_to_id` takes a `DATE` as an input parameter rather than a `VARCHAR2` that represents a date, and assuming that the `:DateEnd` bind variable is a `VARCHAR2`, you would need something like

```
ml.convert_date_to_id( to_date( :DateEnd, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) + 1 )
```

or

```
ml.convert_date_to_id( to_date( :DateEnd, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) + interval '1' day )
```

Comment: I don't think it's a varchar, although I'm not sure how the binding is working here -- when I use that query in SSRS, the dataset parameter is bound to a report parameter that is defined as a date.

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_date` to convert the value. For example:

```
select &date + 1 from dual
```

Informing `to_date('29052012','ddmmyyyy')` works fine

Informing `'29-may-2012'` gives `ORA-01722: invalid number`